# apache zeppelin programmatic test. Websockets calls

Tags: automated-tests, integration-testing, spring-websocket, apache-zeppelin

Trying to use spring websocet library to connect to zeppelin, running on default port 8080.

When I use :

```
ClientWebSocketContainer container = new ClientWebSocketContainer(
            webSocketClient(), "ws://localhost:8080");
```

Get error :

> java.io.IOException: Connect failure
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.ClientContainer.connect(ClientContainer.java:157) ~[javax-websocket-client-impl-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.ClientContainer.connectToServer(ClientContainer.java:180) ~[javax-websocket-client-impl-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient$1.call(StandardWebSocketClient.java:152) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.socket.client.standard.StandardWebSocketClient$1.call(StandardWebSocketClient.java:149) ~[spring-websocket-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
>   Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.UpgradeException: Didn't switch protocols
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeConnection.validateResponse(UpgradeConnection.java:314) ~[websocket-client-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeConnection.read(UpgradeConnection.java:241) ~[websocket-client-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.we...

When I try to connect to 8081 (what the docs say is the websocket port):

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.finishConnect(SelectorManager.java:340) ~[jetty-io-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]

On browser I can connect to 8080 and not make notebooks.

Want to automate and write test cases for our notebooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your ws url is a bit malformed, could you try with `ws://localhost:8080/ws`?

Update:
There's similar example in Zeppelin codebase itself, say for getting note. For example [here](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/zeppelin-zengine/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/notebook/repo/zeppelinhub/websocket/ZeppelinClient.java#L225) the method for getting note and [here](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/zeppelin-zengine/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/notebook/repo/zeppelinhub/websocket/ZeppelinClient.java#L253) is the crafted message that is sent via ws api. Also [this class](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/zeppelin-zengine/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/notebook/socket/Message.java) points to the structure of socket message.

Comment: thanks that helped but still not able to list notebooks. but its a start. have u got a working sample anywhere on github or other open src?

Comment: There's similar example in Zeppelin codebase itself, say for getting note. For example [here](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/zeppelin-zengine/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/notebook/repo/zeppelinhub/websocket/ZeppelinClient.java#L225) the method for getting note and [here](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/zeppelin-zengine/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/notebook/repo/zeppelinhub/websocket/ZeppelinClient.java#L225) is the crafted message that is sent via ws api.

Comment: Can you embed your comment in to answer by edit ? might help others. i'm trying to figure out that code

Comment: done update. also added class with ws message structure